# Failed to mount "Volume" The given volume was not found

Tags: malware, linux, access-control, hardware, boot

I have been experiencing the following problem since a long time now:
So, When I start my computer and I get my Xubuntu op system Desktop, I always get an usb icon to be shown up on my Desktop.
When it is happening, no devices are plugged in.
I always try to open it, but I did not manage, instead I get an error message as (Failed to mount "Volume" The given volume was not found).

What is more, I always check my devices, as I open the Disks utility tool and I surprisly see the a Generic-Multi-Card is showing up again and again. But I can not do anything with it, I mean I can not open, remove or modify it.

I really want to get rid of that strange device.

I also uploaded 3 png files, where we can see the above mentioned problem.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nksfe.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfiwR.jpg]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtT4y.png]

Can someone help me please?
Is there any tool to identify this?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtT4y.png]

Using lsusb command:

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0138 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5138 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0461:4d0f Primax Electronics, Ltd HP Optical Mouse
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

I checked it and yes it was mounting when i inserted a sd card.
But, there are still 4 interesting things what i do not understand.

1. I have never seen this icon showing up on my desktop + on disk utility before.
2. What is 54 Megabyte size showing under the icon on my the desktop?
3. a member of my family is using the same acer model laptop, he is also using xubuntu too, on her desktop the icon is not showing up + we can not see the sd card place on disk utility either.
4. As i have already mentioned it on my post, this icon is also showing up in my virtulbox, even if i disable every connection from my Host to virtualbox guest.

Comment: What is the make/model of the machine are you running? What does `lsusb` show (add to your question)?

Comment: Hi, Acer Aspire laptop.and I am also using

Comment: Hi, Acer Aspire laptop and I am also using Amd Gygabyte Pc. 
But what I have posted, that is considering to Acer Aspire laptop where I used lsusb command.
I would like to post that screen as well, but I am new here, can you let me know how i can do it please?
I mean, do I have to make a new question or not? 

Anyway last time, I got this usb icon using my Amd pc, what is more I installed xubuntu in Virtualbox using my Amd pc and this usb icon was also showing up on the Desktop of xubuntu in Virtualbox.

Comment: No reason to use a screen shot, just edit your question and copy/paste the text from the terminal.

Comment: Going back to your 1st screenshot, what happens if you click on the **User Defaults** button then uncheck *Show in user interface*?

Comment: I copied, but when I wanted to paste it, I got an error message as too long by 85 characters, sorry! 10 Devices were listed.

When I clicked on the User Defaults button then unchecked Show in user interface, after that the (x-gvfs-show) text disappeared. 

Do you know what it can cause this problem????

Comment: You can add the text output to your question; just edit it and place it at the end. Personally, I would not worry about this device - it's ready if/when you use it, but not causing any harm.

Comment: Ok, I edited my post above and I managed to copy from the terminal and paste it here.

Comment: Looks like it's a card reader, possibly for an SD card. Will it mount if you insert a card into the reader? Perhaps it's showing a desktop icon for the reader device, even if there is no card inserted to mount?

Comment: i edited my post and pasted my answer there, because i did not manage to paste here.